# How to fix keymap after ubuntu installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, bios

Recently I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my pc alongside Windows 10. I added `nouveau.modeset` to grub boot script to be able to log in (there is an issue on Dell XPS 15, which prevents ubuntu from logging in without this option). After that, I wasn't able to change the screen brightness with the usual shortcut `shift+f11/shift+f12`. I added `apci_backlight=vendor` to the aforementioned grub boot script (`/etc/default/grub`). After that, I was able to change the brightness simply by `f11/f12`. Also, the sound could be changed with `f3/f4` (I was using `shift+f3/shift+f4` before). The problem is that I can't, for instance, reload the page in the browser with `f5`, because the keymap has been changed.

So, the question is: how to change the keymap back again?

Note: The same issue in my Windows installation, so this seems to be a system problem. I already tried to update BIOS firmware to restore the settings, but this didn't work out.

Comment: Use the fn key + f5. It does not seem a Unix problem.

Comment: I also can't use other shortcuts in, for instance, IDEA's. Should I post this question somewhere else?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you certain you didn't just accidentally press the function lock combination (`Fn+Esc`) ?

Comment: In fact, I did. I didn't know about `fn`-reversing, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This was already answered here, and just googling by "Function Keys Dell XPS" will get you to this AskUbuntu question: [How to invert fn keys on Dell Laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/q/88063/494660)

Pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> changes the `Fn lock` so, your function keys will not behave as multimedia/backlight control keys as default, and will be reverted to function keys.